# Seeking explanation for discrepancy between hardcoded and referenced colour in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm having a play with Android Studio.
I'm trying to change the background colour. I've found how to change it but what's puzzling me is that if I substitute the definition (ie the actual hex code) of the colorAccent property I don't see the same colour.
This is the original, which uses `@color/colorAccent`, which ultimately is a hex code defined in the class `R.color`:

[image]

This is what I get when I substitute the hex code that colorAccent references:

[image]

As you can see, I get a shade of grey instead of a shade of red. Why is this?
Thanks. 
[Android Studio 3.2]

Answer (score 1):

It is not shade of red beacuse depend on your select.
You can change color in XML if you hardcode it.
click on side color on left of code :
[image]

then choose your color:
[image]

But if you set it like `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"`
you should change it in color XML

Answer (score 1):

The hex value for `colorAccent` in the `R.java` doesn't refer to the color, but rather the automatically generated unique id for that XML attribute in `colors.xml`. As you can see, the hex values for the variables are all in-order and increasing by 1 each time.

The actual hex code for the color denoted by `colorAccent` is defined in `colors.xml`, and substituting that directly in the `android:background` attribute will work as you expect it to.